# MouseMove event: How to force the Cursor to move horizontal smoothly when Shift Key is being pressed in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to force the Cursor to move horizontally **smoothly** when Shift Key is being pressed WinForm? I can force the mouse to move horizontally using the 2 very little codes below, however, the Cursor is moving with a lot of flashing.

```
           int horizontalPosition = 0; //
            mainForm.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                {
                    Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, horizontalPosition);
                }

            };
```

`KeyDown` to capture the Y position before `MouseMove`

```
            mainForm.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
                    horizontalPosition = Cursor.Position.Y;
            };
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip?view=windowsdesktop-6.0